# Get absolute path of myvim.vim file in Python code block

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to write a vim plugin that uses a Python code block inside of it. I would like to get the full path of `myvim.vim` (`/home/myusername/.vim/bundle/myvim/plugin/myvim.vim`) inside of my python code block. Unfortunately you can't get the path by using `__file__` as in a `.py` file. I can't use `vim.command(':pwd')` either because that just prints the path of the location where the plugin function is called from.

**myvim.vim**

```
function! Myvim()

python << EOF
import vim

vim_path = "full myvim.vim path here"
print vim_path

EOF

endfunction
```

### EDIT

@actionshrimp, I'm trying this:

**myvim.vim**

```
function! Myvim()
    let s:curfile = expand("<sfile>")
    let s:curfiledir = fnamemodify(s:curfile, ":h")

python << EOF
import vim

py vim_path = vim.eval('expand("<sfile>")')
print vim_path

EOF

endfunction
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<sfile>` to get the path of the currently executing vimscript, like so:

```
let s:curfile = expand("<sfile>")
let s:curfiledir = fnamemodify(s:curfile, ":h")
```

To pass that to python you should be able to use:

```
py vim_path = vim.eval('expand("<sfile>")')
```

or if you've set the variable:

```
py vim_path = vim.eval('s:curfile')
```

For clarity here's a full example (saved as 'D:\tmp\test.vim'):

```
python << EOF
import vim

vim_path = vim.eval('expand("<sfile>")')
print vim_path

EOF
```

When I have it open and type `:so %` it shows 'D:\tmp\test.vim' at the bottom.

Comment: I get a SyntaxError when I implement `py vim_path = vim.eval('expand("<sfile>")')`. Just writing `vim_path = vim.eval('expand("<sfile>")')` instead outputs `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found`.

Comment: `vim_path = vim.command(":py vim_path = vim.eval('expand(\"<sfile>\")')")` produces a `TypeError` as well.

Comment: Hmm strange, it works here. What about if you set the variable in vimscript, and use vim.eval to just get the variable's value? Also just to double check, you aren't just trying this out as commands are you? Is it actually being run as part of your script, with `:so %` or similar? If I just run `:py print vim.eval('expand("<sfile>")')` I just get 'None' displayed.

Comment: One other thing, I also have `set encoding=utf8` in my vimrc which could possibly make a difference? What do you see for `:set encoding` ?

Comment: `:set encoding` returns `encoding=utf-8` so that's ok. Could you look at the edit I made in the original post to make sure if I'm doing what you meant?

Comment: Ah, you won't need the py at the start of the line as you're already inside the python command with the `python << EOF` at the top. (py is the shortening of python). I guess that might be a typo in your example though, in which case it looks fine to me :(